# PostgreSQL Design for Products and Inventory with Color/size matrix

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I try to deal with a complex product database design. I stuck on nested data structure.

Structure;

Product has colors
Color has images, sizes (L, XL)
Size has stocks (5 stock count)

What i do;

Product -> 
    Id,
    Name,
    Price,
    Active,
    Colors (Color.id),
    Images (ProductImage.id),
    Stocks (ProductStock.id),
    Order

Product_color ->
    product_id,
    color_id

Color ->
    Id,
    Name

Product_ProductImage ->
    product_id,
    product_image_id

ProductImage ->
    Id,
    Url,
    ThumbUrl,
    Color (Color.id),
    Order

Product_ProductStock ->
    product_id,
    product_stock_id

ProductStock ->
    Id,
    Count,
    Color (Color.id),
    Size  (Size.id)

Size ->
    Id,
    Name

I put them all in product table because orm (waterline) allow to one level joins.

Questions

1- What do you think about my design?
2- What is advantages or disadvantages?
3- What would you do?

Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would write out the create table statements with foreign key relationships.  The way it's written may lead to lots of assumptions by the reader.

Comment: I added relations. I will add table create statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple issues.

1. You have no constraints here which can address product A having 3 sizes and product B having 4 sizes.  If it were me I would add a product_size table with a mapping to constrain that.  If for now they are always the same, you can just fill them in automatically, but as they diverge (and in the real world, they will diverge), you can properly handle it.
2. In my experience stock works best with an append-only approach, so you need to be able to handle movements in and movements out.  I don't see anything wrong with your discussion here but you probably want to settle on a convention like + for in and - for out, and add a timestamp.